# Trying to retrieve value from JSON on marker click

Tags: javascript, json

How could I go about retrieving the `value` property from the geoJSON when I click on a specific map marker (leaflet.js)? I’ve tried with the following and similar code but I can’t seem to get it to work.

### Sample geoJSON

```
var geojsonFeature = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "marker-color": "#f85047",
                "marker-size": "medium",
                "value": 130
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    146.3622826337814,
                    -41.187067757423826
                ]
            }
        },
    ]
};
```

### JS

```
marker.on('click', function(e){
    alert(this.geojsonFeature.features.properties.value);
});
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CodyW129/9kk8z2cu/)

Comment: A JSFiddle would be helpful so debugging would be easier. It’s easy to find out what `this` is in the function when you debug it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you show in the question:

```
alert(geojsonFeature.features[0].properties.value);
```